# Want to cause a build error for bad input

Tags: jekyll, liquid

Here is a my blog post:

```
---
last-medical-review: 2022-12-03
---
Some post
```

And then there is a layout that reads this front matter and renders the page. All pages need to have the medical review date specified. (And there are plenty of other rules.)

Is it possible to trigger some error conditionally if this front matter element is missing? I am hoping the build can fail as a fatal error.

Comment: Depending on how that variable is used, you can maybe use the `liquid.strict_variables` option (see [here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/liquid/))? That would fail if you try to use the variable when it's not specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is a layout somewhere that does something like this:

```html
<p>Last medical review: {{ page.last-medical-review }}</p>
```

then you can add the following to your `_config.yml`:

```yaml
liquid:
  strict_variables: true
```

which will result in a build error like this if `last-medical-review` isn't defined in the front matter:

```
  Liquid Exception: Liquid error (line 7): undefined variable minima in /tmp/jekylltest/_layouts/post.html
                    ------------------------------------------------
      Jekyll 4.3.1   Please append `--trace` to the `serve` command 
                     for any additional information or backtrace. 
                    ------------------------------------------------
```